# Is there a way to use either HTML or JS so that every few seconds a new message is shown on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make something where I have a bank of phrases or questions and every few seconds or every time the page is refreshed a new message is shown.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Which part of this are you having trouble with? Selecting a random phrase from the array, or doing it every few seconds?

Answer (score -1):

```
setInterval(() => {
  alert("My message");
}, 1000);
```

Where you replace `1000` with the number of milliseconds you want the message to repeat. `1000` milliseconds = 1 second.

Comment: He wants a new message each time, not the same message.

Comment: @Barmar My bad! why is it such a problem for me to read?... anyways, from what it seems like the question is off-topic, would it be okay for me to edit the answer to help them or leave it as it is?